# Excel - Count matching Items, comparing a row with a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to compare the similarity of a series of sets of data...

I have a series of columns of 20 values (numbered 1-20), and corresponding rows of 20 values (also numbered 1-20).

The columns are along the top and the rows are down the side of a matrix grid.

I would like to count how many of the values in the columns are the same as the values in the rows (and in the same corresponding position).

The output on a 3 x 3 (rather than a 20 x 20 grid) would be like this:

```
          Cols 
          A B C
          1 3 1
          2 2 3
          3 1 1
rows     ______
A 1 2 3 | 3 1 1
B 3 2 1 | 1 3 0
C 1 3 1 | 1 0 3
```

What INDEX / MATCH / ARRAY function can do this for me, without a 20 mega-nested calc e.g. =IF(C7=F3,1+IF(... etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following array formula can accomplish this.

```
=SUM(IF(D$1:D$3=TRANSPOSE($A4:$C4), 1, 0))
```

It compares each cell in the ranges and adds 1 to the total for each cell that is identical. The `TRANSPOSE` function is used to convert the rows to columns so that they can be compared.

[image: screenshot]

Note that this is an array formula, so it must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Enter the formula into the top-left cell (`D4` in my screenshot), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then copy to the remaining cells.

Comment: bdr9 - you rock! TRANSPOSE, wasn't aware you could use that in a formula...

Comment: @Poolio I'm glad to hear it worked for you. If this answered your question, then please mark my answer as accepted with the green check mark button.

Comment: I'd love to show you my output, but I'm a newb on this forum... :(

Comment: @Poolio You could take a screenshot using the Snipping Tool in Windows 7 or higher, and then upload it to an image-sharing website such as imgur.com.

Comment: Ta-da!! http://imgur.com/cUsJQyT

Comment: @Poolio Wow, that looks great!